# How to handle the Oath2.0 credentials in the APK files

Tags: android, oauth

These days, mobile apps commonly leverage Oauth /OpenIdConnect-based authentication and authorization frameworks. To achieve this, the Oauth clients (the App running on android/IOS) must have a few credentials - e.g., Client_ID and Client_Secrete to obtain the Auth token from the Authorization Server for communicating with Backend services. How can this sensitive information be bundled in the APK files with an acceptable level of security? The risk is that the secrets (client_secret) can be disclosed by reverse engineering, and a fake App can be compiled using these credentials (Identity Spoofing).
When the App is installed onto the Device, these can be managed in a secure place (KeyStore) that is specific to the Device and platform. But until the installation, these have to be secured.
Code obfuscation is one technique that does not guarantee confidentiality. Is there a better solution available ? What is the standard practice?

Comment: *" Is there a better solution available ?"* - Yes, use PKCE flow in OAuth so that you don't need to store any secrets on the client side or in the APK. See for example [Build an Android App Using OAuth 2.0 and PKCE](https://cloudentity.com/developers/app-dev-tutorials/android/android_pkce_tutorial/).

Comment: Currently we are working with ZOOM SDK for one of the online meeting App. However the SDK does not support PKCE yet. Is there some alternate ways that has acceptable way of handling credentials in the binary file as a short term solution ?